# Python-Pandas: How to improve speed of row-by-row calculation with dataframes? (SettingWithCopyWarning)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I'm trying to implement a simple energy storage calculator as part of a larger program. I have a large dataframe (total_profile) which contains all kinds of hourly data points. Here I specifically want to check if I have excess solar energy available and then put it into storage if there is still capacity remaining. A major issue is that I need to work row-by-row as the value of the previous row will be used to change the value of the current row. The code seems to work in principle, but it is really slow compared to everything else in the simulation.

```
  for hour in range(1,8760):
    # 1. Add excess solar heat to the previous hour's stored energy and make sure it doesn't exceed the maximum storage capacity
    total_profile['Thermal storage'].iloc[hour] = np.minimum(thermal_storage_capacity, total_profile['Thermal storage'].iloc[hour-1] + total_profile['ST excess'].iloc[hour])

    # 2. If there is heat demand after utilizing solar, take energy out of the storage, but no more than is stored
    energy_from_storage = np.minimum(total_profile['Heat demand after ST'].iloc[hour], total_profile['Thermal storage'].iloc[hour])

    # 3. Check whether any heat demand remains after utilizing stored energy
    total_profile['Heat demand after ST'].iloc[hour] = total_profile['Heat demand after ST'].iloc[hour] - energy_from_storage

    # 4. Update the storage status after taking energy out of it
    total_profile['Thermal storage'].iloc[hour] = total_profile['Thermal storage'].iloc[hour] - energy_from_storage
```

When running the code, I'm getting the "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" warning on commands 1, 3 and 4. I'm thinking that this is probably related to the speed issue. Here I'm just trying to access single values and update some of the values in the dataframe. Is there some better way to do this?

According to help related to the warning, I tried to use .copy() when accessing the total_profile dataframe, but it didn't have any effect. Any ideas? The dataframe includes a timestamp index, if that is helpful.

-Edit-

I made a minimal working example of the code. The problem is, that this example doesn't actually give out the warning that the real system does. Yes, the actual dataframe has more rows and more columns, but the specific columns that are used here are similar (same names and data types). I didn't think that dataframe size would affect the appearance of these warnings?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

thermal_storage_capacity = 100
energy_from_storage = 0
total_profile = pd.DataFrame({"Thermal storage": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                              "ST excess": [0, 0, 5, 20, 40, 70, 0, 20, 5, 0],
                              "Heat demand after ST": [100, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 50]})
start_time = time.time()
                  
for hour in range(1,10):
    # 1. Add excess solar heat to the previous hours stored energy and make sure it doesn't exceed the maximum storage capacity
    # 2. If there is heat demand after utilizing solar, take energy out of the storage, but no more than is stored
    # 3. Check whether any heat demand remains after utilizing stored energy
    # 4. Update the storage status after taking energy out of it

  total_profile['Thermal storage'].iloc[hour] = np.minimum(thermal_storage_capacity, total_profile['Thermal storage'].iloc[hour-1] + total_profile['ST excess'].iloc[hour])
  energy_from_storage = np.minimum(total_profile['Heat demand after ST'].iloc[hour], total_profile['Thermal storage'].iloc[hour])
  total_profile['Heat demand after ST'].iloc[hour] = total_profile['Heat demand after ST'].iloc[hour] - energy_from_storage
  total_profile['Thermal storage'].iloc[hour] = total_profile['Thermal storage'].iloc[hour] - energy_from_storage     

end_time = time.time()
duration = end_time-start_time
```

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEsJ8.png)

Here the goal would be to reduce the time it takes to run the loop by 90% or so, if possible.

Comment: Please, can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the expected output for this sample?

Comment: why not store previous row in a temporary variable? at the end of for loop: `previous_row = current_row`

Comment: also, you might want to work on `df.values`, using numpy array indexing instead of pandas indexing.

Comment: Thank you! Working with temporary numpy arrays with df.values increased the speed 10x! Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

> major issue is that I need to work row-by-row as the value of the previous row will be used to change the value of the current row.

If you always need the value of the previous row you could use the [Series.shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html).